# Common legend for all the pie charts using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create the 7 plots using the below code. I would like to have a common legend for all the 7 plots, preferably in the top right corner. For green region, legend should be 'Sending data', for red region, it should be 'Not sending data'. I tried using figlegend but could not achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,10), dpi=1600)
 ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,0))
 plt.pie(df_14,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS1')
 ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 1))
 plt.pie(df_24,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS2')
 ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 2))
 plt.pie(df_34,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS3')
 ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 3))
 plt.pie(df_44,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS4')
 ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 0))
 plt.pie(df_54,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS5')
 ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 1))
 plt.pie(df_64,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS6')
 ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 2))
 line7 = plt.pie(df_74,colors=("g","r"))
 plt.title('LOGS7')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legend needs only to be called once otherwise you would get 7 different legends showing. An example of which I have shown below. Note that you will have to substitute in your own data into `ax.pie()`:

```
data1 = (10,90)  # some data to be plotted
data2 = (40,50)
data3 = (70,30)

labels = ['Sending Data', 'Not Sending Data'] #legend labels to be plotted
colors = ['green', 'red']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,4),(0,0))
ax1.pie(data1, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS1')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 1))
ax2.pie(data2, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS2')

ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 2))
ax3.pie(data3, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS3')

ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (0, 3))
ax4.pie(data1, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS4')

ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 0))
ax5.pie(data2, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS5')

ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 1))
ax6.pie(data3, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.title('LOGS6')

ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 4), (1, 2))
patches, texts = ax7.pie(data1, colors=colors, startangle=90) #use this plot to show the legend
plt.title('LOGS7')
plt.legend(patches, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(2.3, 2), prop={'size':14}) #show the legend defined in labels
#change values of 'bbox_to_anchor' to move the legend to the desired location

plt.axis('equal') # Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.94) #adjust the spacing on right to see legend clearly
plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]